# How Authenticate by WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, authentication, membership

I Passed userName and Pass to webmethod in .aspx page by Ajax in Json Format,
now i want authenticate users and redirect user to same page and update LoginView with LogedIn State;

How Can i do it?
here's my WebMethod

```
[WebMethod]
    // [ [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet=false)]
    public static void login(object myData)
    {

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<nameVal> myfrm = js.Deserialize<List<nameVal>>(myData.ToString());
      //  MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(myfrm.SingleOrDefault(rs=>rs.name=="userName").value);

        if (  Membership.ValidateUser(myfrm[0].value,myfrm[1].value))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(myfrm[0].value, myfrm[1].value);
            //FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(myfrm[0].value, false);

            FormsAuthenticationTicket tkt;
            string cookiestr;
            HttpCookie ck;
            tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, myfrm[0].value, DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), true, "my custom data");
            cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt);
            ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookiestr);

            ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath; 
            //  ******* now i must somthing like this: -->  Response.Cookies.Add(ck);
            // but im in static method don't have respons request objects
            // i want respons in json form and proccess the json


           // return "Success";
        }
        else
        {
            //return "Faild";
        }

    }
```

so tanks

Comment: so what's the problem.. set session/cookie and use that on your redirect page..

Comment: How update LoginView and LogginName controls States,

Comment: how Set Session Or Cookie

Comment: Like this **FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(myfrm[0].value, true);** how Response? im in static webmethod and don't have access to request and response object

Comment: you always have context .. there you have request and response

Comment: your are right. i have this static method **HttpContext.Current.Respons();**

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```cs
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(myfrm[0].value, createPersistentCookie: false);
return FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(user.Name, false);
```

and then in your javascript:

```js
var onSuccess = function (result) {
   if (result === null) {
      // login failed
      return;
   }
   window.location.href = result;
};

PageMethods.login(myData, onSuccess);
```

This unfortunately still has a "silent" `ThreadAbortException` that I can't seem to get rid of, but it doesn't seem to cause any problems. I think it's probably unavoidable and benign.